# Regular expression to transform string to list (Python)

Tags: python, regex, string, list

A program outputs a file with lines of the following format

```
{Foo} Bar Bacon {Egg}
```

where `Foo` and `Egg` could, but do not have to, be made up of several words. `Bar` and `Bacon` always are a single word.

I need to get `Bar` in a variable for my further code. I imagine that this would work if I split the sting at a matching regular expression. This would return a list of the four elements and thus I could easily get out the second element with `list[1]`.

How would I write such a regular expression?

I need to split the sting on single spaces `' '`, but only if that single space is not surrounded by text in curly braces.

`\s(?=[a-zA-Z{}])` gives me all the spaces and thus behaves exactly like `' '`. How can I exclude the spaces in the curly braces?

Comment: Try `re.search(r'(?<=} )\S+', str).group()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `{[^}]*}\s(\w+)`

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.search(r'{[^}]*}\s(\w+)', '{Foo} Bar Bacon {Egg}').group(1)
Bar
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NPJa6r/1/)

Explanation:

- `{[^}]*}` first you match the first section inside curly braces
- `\s` then a whitespace
- `(\w+)` then the second section; you put it in a capturing group, so it's available in search results as `group(1)`

> `re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>
> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding match object. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search

Answer (score 2):

This might help.

```
>>> import re
>>> line = '{Foo} Bar Bacon {Egg}'
>>> m = re.search(r'}\s+(\S+)\s+', line)
>>> m.group(1)
'Bar'
>>>
```

I just searched for any word that follows a close-brace. I used `()` to group that word so that I could access it later with `m.group()`

If you really want all four elements, try `re.findall()`:

```
>>> line = '{Foo Goo} Bar Bacon {Egg Foo}'
>>> re.findall(r'{.*?}|\S+', line)
['{Foo Goo}', 'Bar', 'Bacon', '{Egg Foo}']
```